# How to check if an element exists using if - elif - else

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown menu and I need to check its entries. If there is no entry , I can add new entries, if there is only one entry I remove it and add new entries and when I have many entries (>=2) I cannot proceed to adding entries. I can check it via `person_rem_btn`. If I have only one button `doc_person_table:0:person_rem_btn` I can proceed If I have a second button `doc_person_table:1:person_rem_btn` I cannot proceed.

I get this exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table:1:person_rem_btn']/span[1]"}
```

However, that's the point, this element may not be available, I just check its existence. I would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table:1:person_rem_btn']/span[1]") == True:
   print ("there are already many entries")
   driver.close()
elif (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table:1:person_rem_btn']/span[1]") == False and driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table:0:person_rem_btn']/span[1]") == True):
   print ("there is only one entry, it will be removed to proceed")
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table:0:person_rem_btn']/ span[1]"))).click()
else:
    print ("there is no entry, you can proceed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_element_by_xpath` doesn't return `True` or `False`, it returns `WebElement` or throws `NoSuchElementException`. You can use `find_elements_by_xpath` to get a list and check if this list contains any elements. Start with waiting for an unrelated element that can indicate the page is loaded

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id^='frmMain:doc_person_table")))
# assuming this element will always appear when the page is loaded

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table:1:person_rem_btn']/span[1]")
if elements: # more verbose if len(elements) > 0
    print ("there are already many entries")
    driver.close()
else:
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table:0:person_rem_btn']/span[1]")
    if elements:
        print ("there is only one entry, it will be removed to proceed")
        elements[0].click()
    else:
        print ("there is no entry, you can proceed")
```

Comment: thank you for your time, i still get the same exception.

Comment: @jitlp It should be `find_elements_by_xpath`, see updated answer.

Comment: you're right, i copy pasted it without checking. Ok the exception is solved, but no check is made. it prints straight "there is no entry" . is this thought as a different question?

Comment: @jitlp You can add a `WebDriverWait` for unrelated element that you know will always be there and indicate the page was loaded. See updated answer.

Comment: this WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table']"))) causes a new exception for stale element reference. I cannot refresh the page as I work on a popup form

Comment: @jitlp this element was just an example, you can choose any other element. It's just meant to give an indication the page is loaded. I'm not familiar with the site so I posted based on the locators from the question.

Comment: sure, I used another element,I used it here as your example. however the problem comes for other elements not this specific.

Comment: @jitlp are you referring to the elements located in `elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='frmMain:doc_person_table:0:person_rem_btn']/span[1]")` and `elements[0].click()`? or something else not related to this?

Comment: i'm reffering to a third element

Comment: @jitlp It sounds like a new question, it will be hard answering in the comments without seeing more detailed code and html, but you should remember that moving to another page or refreshing the page (`click()` sometimes can cause the page to refresh) invalidates all the previously located elements and you need to relocate them.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can adapt and one of the approach would be to create a *List* of the dropdown entries inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and probe the list size:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id*='doc_person_table'][id$='person_rem_btn']>span")))
  if not list:
      print ("there is no entry, you can proceed")
      # other steps
  elif len(list) == 1
      print ("there is only one entry, it will be removed to proceed")
      # other steps
  else:
      print ("there are already many entries")
      break
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'doc_person_table') and contains(@id, 'person_rem_btn')]/span")))
  if not list:
      print ("there is no entry, you can proceed")
      # other steps
  elif len(list) == 1
      print ("there is only one entry, it will be removed to proceed")
      # other steps
  else:
      print ("there are already many entries")
      break
  ```